# Oracle Apex checkbox

Tags: checkbox, oracle-apex

I have a page within my app with a Checkbox option.

The idea is basically to allow the user to select/unselect it if the change needs to be applied for every *Sales Rep*.

**Something like this:**

If checkbox is clicked     `=` Change would be applied to all territories owned by the Rep

If checkbox is not clicked `=` Change would only be applied to the selected territory

I can't seem to get the checkbox clicked option to work.
I'm using an `instr` function to get a value out of it but it doesn't work:

```
select instr(':' ||:P11_CHECK_FOR_ALL|| ':', 'Request') into v_number_terr from dual;

if v_number_terr >0
```

(`P11_CHECK_FOR_ALL` is my checkbox Item / 'Request' is a word that's part of its label)

[my checkbox pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNYgh.png)

I'm trying to capture (in a process) whether the option is checked or not.
Could someone give me a hand please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In apex a checkbox behaves just like a select list (with multiple selects possible). There is a display value and a return value. If nothing is selected, the page item value will be null. If one or more value are selected, the page item will contain a colon separated list of selected return values.
To handle the select list in a page process, the easiest is to split up the colon separated list in individual values using `APEX_STRING.SPLIT`

Example (untested):

```
DECLARE
  l_check_for_all apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN
  l_check_for_all := apex_string.split(:P11_CHECK_FOR_ALL,':');
  -- loop through the values. If nothing is selected then the COUNT will be 0 and nothing will be executed.
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_check_for_all.COUNT LOOP
    // do your pl/sql magic. You can reference the current item with l_check_for_all(i)
  END LOOP;
END;
```